# Java.lang.NullPointerException at getapplicationContext() while initiating adapter

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

While running the project on Android emulator,I face the exception as java.lang.NullPointerException at getApplicationContext.Please help me to resolve this issue.

**Error**

```
07-19 15:08:07.811: D/AndroidRuntime(366): Shutting down VM
07-19 15:08:07.811: W/dalvikvm(366): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-19 15:08:07.841: E/AndroidRuntime(366): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 15:08:07.841: E/AndroidRuntime(366): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.TfsMutualFund/org.TfsMutualFund.loading}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 15:08:07.841: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
07-19 15:08:07.841: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

07-19 15:08:07.841: E/AndroidRuntime(366): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 15:08:07.841: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:100)
07-19 15:08:07.841: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at org.TfsMutualFund.loading.<init>(loading.java:23)
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 package="org.TfsMutualFund">   
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:name=".globalAdapter" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name=".loading"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TFSManinActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"/>
</application>
```

**loading.java**

```
package org.TfsMutualFund;

public class loading extends Activity{
private static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private globalAdapter adpt = ((globalAdapter)getApplicationContext());
private String ServicePath = adpt.getServicePath();
private String ServiceName = adpt.getServiceName();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loading);
 if(isOnline())
    new AsyncLoad().execute();
 else
```

Comment: You can just use "this" instead of calling getApplicationContext() in your loading activity

Comment: don't post everything.just post the block of code where its getting error!!!

Comment: And also do those initializations in onCreate() and not before that!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't initialize it before `OnCreate()`, you can't get Context with there, do it in `onCreate()`.

```
private globalAdapter adpt;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loading);
    adpt  = ((globalAdapter)getApplicationContext());
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lalit. But after initializing it in OnCreate method it shows same error.

Comment: did you remove `private globalAdapter adpt = ((globalAdapter)getApplicationContext());` as global?

Comment: I declare it as global and initialize it in the Oncreate() method.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Dont initialize the below before the onCreate, let the views get their ids first

```
private globalAdapter adpt = ((globalAdapter)getApplicationContext());
private String ServicePath = adpt.getServicePath();
private String ServiceName = adpt.getServiceName();
```

**2.** Just Declare them....

```
private globalAdapter adpt;
private String ServicePath;  
private String ServiceName;
```

**3.** Its because when the Activity is not formed, how can you get the Context to that activity, cause you are using the `getApplicationContext()` to get the current Activity context.

Comment: Thanks Xitij,But even after initializing it in Oncreate() method it shows the same error..